# Clearing python list with slice operator copy

Tags: python, python-2.6

I just came across following python 2.6 code python

```
for i in elements[:]:
    elements.remove(i)
```

I'm trying to figure out the reason to use this syntax for clearing the list.
I understand the concept of inplace deletion, but why not for example:

```
del elements[:]
```

or

```
elements[:] = []
```

Thx !

Comment: If there's no condition within the loop then there's no need to use a loop there. Perhaps the author isn't aware of the other methods.

Comment: That's bad code. Did you see it here? Maybe it's just a demo of copying a list to avoid the pitfalls of deleting while iterating.

Comment: The code is as it is. And it's some "real" code. But thanks, you're comforting me in what I thought. But when it comes to understand someone else's code, I'm always afraid to miss some subtle point...

Comment: There's also `elements.clear()`, which is probably the most explicit way you can show what you're doing.

Comment: @Blckknght But it is only available in Python 3.3+.

Answer (score 0):

You must think of Python lists as 'pointers'.

For example, if you declare a list like so:

```
elements = [1, 2, 3]
```

This would be seen in memory like this:

```
elements → [ ↓, ↓, ↓ ]
             1  2  3
```

So when you change an element in the list you are doing something like this:

```
elements[1] = 4
                4
elements → [ ↓, ↑, ↓ ]
             1  2  3
```

Notice how the number 2 has no pointer reference so it will be 'gone or lost from memory' and it's no longer accessible. So the same happens when you re-assign the variable itself:

```
elements[:] = []

         []
elements ↑     [ ↓, ↓, ↓ ]
                 1  4  3
```

The key to understand here is that the original list is also 'gone or from lost from memory' and it's no longer accessible. Another important key to understand is that the slicing:

`elements[:]` Get's you the pointer (or the arrow in my illustrations) that the variable is referring to.

So that's why it's exactly the same to use

`del elements[:]` (I delete the arrow and set a new arrow to an empty list)

or

`elements[:] = []` (I make the variable now point to a new empty list, the old arrow will be deleted when dereferenced)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm aware of what you are explaining... And, someone corrects me if I'm wrong, but "del elements[:] and elements[:] = [ ]" doesn't actually delete the list, it empties it "inplace". i.e. id(elements) before and after are the same... My question was about some subtlety in the "for" syntax I mentioned.